# Is there a way to auto update offset in a query when tijdtot is negative

Tags: mysql, limit, offset

i have a question.  I have a query that calculates how many days it is until the next grand_prix event in the list.  I then work with offset and I actually want to automatically go to the next positive number if the event becomes 0 days or a negative number.  i calculate the Timeto in the table between datetime and curdate.

```
SELECT
    gp_naam, VT1, VT2, VT3, kwalificatie, race, image, CURDATE(),
    DATEDIFF(VT1, CURDATE()) AS Tijdtot
FROM grand prix
ORDER BY Tijdtot ASC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

I've already tried everything and I think I need to do something with WHERE Timeto >0 but it won't accept it and result in an error.  does anyone know how i can solve this?  thanks in advance for your help and input

Comment: You cannot use expressions for the LIMIT args in MySQL. Please do not post images of your data! Update your question with a markdown or ascii table of your data and your expected result. You are probably looking for: `WHERE VT1 > NOW()` or `WHERE VT1 > CURDATE()` depending on when you want it to change which ones are being returned.

Comment: Oh sorry. I will remove the images. I added them so it was clear what i was looking for with the query... i tried your input and you are really a hero... exactly what i was lookong for. Working like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to get your countdown:

```
SELECT
    gp_naam, VT1, VT2, VT3, kwalificatie, race, image,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, NOW(), VT1) AS days,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, NOW(), VT1) % 24 AS hours,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, NOW(), VT1) % 60 AS mins
FROM grand_prix
WHERE VT1 > NOW()
ORDER BY VT1 ASC
LIMIT 1;
```